# Monge Ampere equations

Tags: complex-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am a graduate student trying to understand complex Monge-Ampere equations(mostly on complex manifolds with or without boundary, but also in C^n), but I can't put my hand on any monograph/textbook discussing this problem thoroughly. Is there anything out there that could help me? If there isn't, can any of you folks tell me with what articles I should start my reading?

Any piece of information is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should start with Maciej Klimek's book "Pluripotential theory". Try it, and you'll tell me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Kołodziej's](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2172891) and [Klimek's](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1150978) books are very good, and [Demailly's online book](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf) also has useful material. You can also try with Zbigniew Błocki's lecture notes

http://gamma.im.uj.edu.pl/~blocki/publ/ln/wykl.pdf

http://gamma.im.uj.edu.pl/~blocki/publ/ln/tln.pdf

This classical paper of [Caffarelli-Kohn-Nirenberg-Spruck](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cpa.3160380206) is also a must!

For the case of compact Kähler manifolds, apart from Błocki's notes above, I would also recommend [Siu's book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0904673) and [this Asterisque book](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0525893) in French.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like I have a lot of reading to do this winter :)

Answer (score 5):

Klimek's book is a good starting point for the theory in $\mathbb{C}^n$. For manifolds, go to:

Kołodziej, Sławomir The complex Monge-Ampère equation and pluripotential theory.  Mem. Amer. Math. Soc.  178  (2005),  no. 840, x+64 pp.

Answer (score 5):

Though it doesn't focus exclusively on complex Monge-Ampere equations, I learnt a lot from Gilbarg and Trudinger's book "Elliptic pdes of second order".

Answer (score 4):

It's rather too late. However, Vincent Guedj and Ahmed Zeriahi, Degenerate Complex Monge-Ampere Equations seems to be a very carefully written book.